# Why cannot template parameters deduced when trying to get the last parameter of a pack?

Tags: c++

Look at this code:

```
template <typename ...TYPES>
struct List {
};

template <typename LIST>
struct Last;

template <typename ...HEAD, typename LAST>
struct Last<List<HEAD..., LAST>> {
    typedef LAST Value;
};
```

Here, `Last`'s template parameters cannot be deduced. Why? Is there a simpler solution than doing recursion until one type remains?

`First`'s implementation works straightforwardly:

```
template <typename LIST>
struct First;

template <typename FIRST, typename ...TAIL>
struct First<List<FIRST, TAIL...>> {
    typedef FIRST Value;
};
```

Comment: Short answer, no. The reason being no parameter may appear after a parameter pack

Comment: I- you don't want to roll your own, you could write `using value = tuple_element<sizeof...(HEAD) - 1, tuple<HEAD...>>`

Comment: @PasserBy: thanks, for the suggestion, but I've just faced this problem while implementing my own `tuple` :) Not a big deal, I've solved this with recursion, I'm just curious why this works this way.

Comment: `HEAD...` will match everything and there will be nothing left for `LAST`. There is no all-but-one matching rule.